# Roslyn analyzer crashes Visual Studio when T has a property of type IList<T>

Tags: masstransit, roslyn-code-analysis

I have a MassTransit consumer that responds to a message with the following interface:

```
public interface Foo {
  IList<Foo> Foos { get; }
  Bar Bar { get; }
}
```

MassTransit.Analyzer is included into my project to help resolving types automagically but when I go and ask the analyzer to add the missing properties Visual Studio crashes. Any idea how to tell the analyzer (Roslyn?) how to only go maybe `n` levels deep?

Comment: This isn't really a question, I'd suggest closing it. You're welcome to submit an issue related to the Analyzer.